# jQuery: Can't select the appended select options

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to coding and just encountered an issue that seems like it should be 
 easy to solve but I couldn't find a working solution all day. None of the other threads here seemed to tackle my exact problem. I've never used jQuery before today, only vanilla JS, so maybe it's something about jQuery that I'm not getting.

I'm working on a form with two select menus. The first menu selects the product and the second menu then gives you more specific options. The second menu is disabled at first and only enabled for certain products of menu1. Also, menu2 has different options depending on the selected product of menu1, which is why I'm using .empty() before appending the new options.

The options for menu2 show up as intended, the only problem is that I can't select them. I get the options, but only the default option is selected.

[Here is the relevant code on codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QYadmq?editors=1010) (I tried using different syntax for the tShirtOptions() function but that didn't do the trick)

```js
const menu1 = document.getElementById("produktart");
const menu2 = document.getElementById("stickstand");

function menuEnabler() {
  menu2.disabled = false;
  menu2.classList.remove("text-muted");
  menu2.classList.add("text-secondary");
}

function menuDisabler() {
  menu2.disabled = true;
  menu2.classList.remove("text-secondary");
  menu2.classList.add("text-muted");
}

function tShirtOptions() {
  $(menu2)
    .empty()
    .append($('<option>', {
      text: "Menu2",
      disabled: true,
      selected: true,
      class: "d-none"
    }))
    .append($('<option>', {
      value: "Vorderteil/Herzstand",
      text: "Vorderteil/Herzstand"
    }))
    .append($('<option>', {
      value: "Rücken",
      text: "Rücken"
    }))
    .append($('<option>', {
      value: "Ärmel",
      text: "Ärmel"
    }))
    .append($('<option>', {
      value: "Kragen",
      text: "Kragen"
    }))


}

function hemdOptions() {
  $(menu2)
    .empty()
    .append('<option disabled selected class="d-none">Menu2</option>')
    .append('<option value="Vorderteil/Herzstand">Vorderteil/Herzstand</option>')
    .append('<option value="Rücken">Rücken</option>')
    .append('<option value="Ärmel">Ärmel</option>')
    .append('<option value="Kragen">Kragen</option>')
    .append('<option value="Manschetten">Manschetten</option>')
}

function capOptions() {
  $(menu2)
    .empty()
    .append('<option disabled selected class="d-none">Menu2</option>')
    .append('<option value="Front">Front</option>')
    .append('<option value="Seite">Seite</option>')
    .append('<option value="Hinten">Hinten</option>')
}

function removeAll() {
  $(menu2)
    .empty()
    .append('<option disabled selected class="d-none text-muted">Menu2</option>')
}

document.addEventListener("change", function(e) {
  let index = menu1.selectedIndex;

  if (index <= 4) {
    menuEnabler();
    tShirtOptions();
  } else if (index === 5) {
    menuEnabler();
    hemdOptions();

  } else if (index === 6) {
    menuEnabler();
    capOptions()

  } else if (index > 6) {
    menuDisabler();
    removeAll();
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container pt-5">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="sr-only" for="produktart">Produktart</label>
    <select class="form-control corners-round text-secondary px-3" id="produktart" name="produktart" required>
      <option disabled selected value class="d-none">Menu1</option>
      <option value="T-Shirts">T-Shirts</option>
      <option value="Polo-Shirts">Polo-Shirts</option>
      <option value="Sweat-Shirts">Sweat-Shirts</option>
      <option value="Jacken">Jacken</option>
      <option value="Hemden/Blusen">Hemden/Blusen</option>
      <option value="Caps">Caps, Strickmützen, Beanies</option>
      <option value="Aktentaschen, Rucksäcke etc.">Taschen, Rucksäcke, Laptoptaschen</option>
      <option value="Wappen">Patches, Abzeichen, Wappen</option>
      <option value="Wimpel">Wimpel</option>
      <option value="Sonstiges">Sonstiges</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="sr-only" for="stickstand">Stickstand</label>
    <select class="form-control corners-round text-muted px-3" id="stickstand" name="stickstand" disabled>
      <option disabled selected class="d-none">Menu2</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  </form>
  <div>
```

Comment: Don't bind the change event to your entire document.

Comment: As @j08691 points out, your `change` event fires any time *anything* changes. When you change the second dropdown, it triggers the event, clearing and repopulating your second dropdown.

Comment: Also, you've mentioned your new to jQuery... the first piece of advice I can give: If you're going to use jQuery, use it **completely**, rather than going back-and-forth between vanilla. IE, targeting elements with jQuery ID selectors instead of `getElementById`, using `.addClass()` and `.removeClass()` instead of `classList`, `$(...).on("change", function() { ... })` instead of `addEventListener`, etc.

Comment: thanks for the advice, will do :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Becuase when you change the second select element, the generic onchange event triggers

```
document.addEventListener("change", function(e) {
```

And you are resetting your menu. Bind the event listener to the select element. Or if you need to do it, check to see if it was the first select element that was altered.

Comment: Aaahhh of course! I knew it had to be something that obvious!